# Difference between adequacy and fluency in ngram

Tags: nlp, bleu

> "When 1-gram precision is high, the reference tends to satisfy
>   adequacy.
>
> When longer n-gram precision is high, the reference tends to account
>   for fluency."

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adequacy:** How much of the source information is preserved?

**Fluency:** How good is the generated target language quality?

**For Machine Translation task,**

English(S-V-O): A dog chased a cat

Reference translation in Hindi would look like:

Hindi(S-O-V): A dog a cat chased

When 1-gram precision is high, correct word-to-word translations will be high but order of those words might not be correct in translated sentence. But still, majority of the source information is preserved.

High 1-gram, low N-gram(2-gram) precision value example: chased dog cat

When N-gram precision is high, order of those words will be preserved to some extent and you would get a fluent sentence in Hindi.

High N-gram(2-gram) precision example: A dog cat chased